# redux-saga why do you need a yield next to the put?

Tags: redux-saga

I have the following saga

```
export function* login(userName, password) {
  yield put({ type: 'LOGIN_DONE', status: 'success', userName: 'test' });

  // Redirect to the landing page
  yield put(push('/location'));
}
```

I'm confused about the following

if I do not put the yield before the first put the action does not get dispatched.  Is this the expected behavior and if so why?  I assumed that having a yield next to the final put should be enough, but this only seems to dispatch only the second action

thanks

Comment: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html

Answer (score 2):

Generator function have the ability to suspend its process until subsequent generator functions are terminated. This is achieved by the use of the *yield* keyword:

> The middleware then executes the yielded Effect as specified by the
>   Effects API. **Meanwhile, the Generator will be suspended until the
>   effect execution terminates.** Upon receiving the result of the
>   execution, the middleware calls next(result) on the Generator passing
>   it the retrieved result as an argument. This process is repeated until
>   the Generator terminates normally or by throwing some error.

So in your case the action might trigger another sagas which might be needed to finish their work before moving on to the next yield. If you wont place that yield, this might cause a side effect where subsequent generator functions are running asynchronously and the outcome wouldn't be as expected.